# -lboost_system does't help for undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()' on cygwin

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, cygwin

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(spider)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
add_executable(spider ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(spider ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(spider Threads::Threads)
target_link_libraries(spider
        ${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARIES}
        ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARIES}
        ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES}
        )
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lboost_system -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED" )
```

This are my includes files from main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;
```

I tried downloading and building boost, it causes tons of trobules, so I decided to use boost which comes with cygwin installer. I do have boost_system and boost in my /include folder, so I don't have to setup boost in my Cmakelists.txt:

[image]

The question is what to do with the error:

> /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:322: undefined reference to
>   `boost::system::system_category()'

As you can see, I've tried **-lboost_system** and **-DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED**, the flags are passed to g++:

> /usr/bin/c++.exe  -lboost_system -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -g 
>   -Wl,--enable-auto-import CMakeFiles/spider.dir/main.cpp.o  -o spider.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libspider.dll.a
>   -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0

but this doesn't help. Any ideas ?

Comment: The order of your link is wrong.  The -lboost_system has to come after your object files.  I don't know how to adjust your CMakefile to fix the issue however.

Comment: Don't add the target_link_libraries manually, use the variables provided by FindBoost.cmake.

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
target_link_libraries(spider boost_system)
```

instead of SET CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS to the end of cmake file fixes the problem, rootcause is that the flag should be in the end, as commenters noted.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to put the library in directly instead of -lboost_system.

```
LIBS= -lboost_thread /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.68.0
```

Not sure why boost_system doesn't resolve correctly in < 1.70 (as I didn't have this error with that version of the libraries, using old version to test other issues)

Hope this helps.